Anticipating DDL run times
I was recently trying to make some ALTER TABLE ALTER COLUMN changes to a postgres table which contained hundreds of millions of rows:

Modifying an existing varchar(10) field to varchar(11) finished in seconds
Modifying an existing varchar[](10) field to varchar[](100) took nearly an hour

What is so fundamentally different between these two DDLs?  What information can be used to better anticipate how long it will take for a DDL to complete?
